# PDO try to make fetch in prepare request

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have make a Database.php class for manage my SQL :

```
<?php
$db = new Database();
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO fity_users(user_email, user_password, 
user_firstname, user_lastname, user_pseudo, user_sexe, user_rank, 
account_isadmin, account_isban, account_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?   , ?)",
['test@test.fr', 'sdfsfds', 'mat', 'mag', 'matieufit', 'h', 100, 0, 0, 
'20/02/2000']);

class Database { 

private $tokenAuth;
private $pdo;

/**
 * Constructeur de la class de gestion de la base de données!
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->tokenAuth = array(
        'bdname' => 'fitaryadb',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'user' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
    );
}

// Fonction privé pour récupérer la connection à la SQL!
private function getPDO() {
    if ($this->pdo === null) {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $this->tokenAuth['bdname'] . ';host='. $this->tokenAuth['host'], $this->tokenAuth['user'], $this->tokenAuth['password']);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    return $pdo;
}

// Effectuer au requête 'query' à la SQL!
public function query($statement) {
    $request = $this->getPDO()->query($statement);
    $result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $result;
}

// Effectuer une requête 'préparée' à la SQL!
public function prepare($statement, $values) {
    $request = $this->getPDO()->prepare($statement);
    $request->execute($values);
    $request->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $result = $request->fetchAll();
    print($result->user_id);
    return $request;
}
}
?>
```

And when I do the prepare it's add on my table, that's no problem but my fetch make error :

```
Fatal error: 
    Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]:  
    General error in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fitarya\Administration\src\Database.php:47  
    Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Fitarya\Administration\src\Database.php(47):  
    PDOStatement->fetchAll() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Fitarya\Administration\src\Database.php(5):  
    Database->prepare('INSERT INTO fit...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fitarya\Administration\src\Database.php on line 47
```

I have try to remove the line of fetch and it's very good work, but I need to have the fetch, same with setFetchMode he doesn't work! (Sorry for my english)

Thanks for help!

Comment: fetch statement doesn't make sense on insertion you know, fetch when you need to select something, maybe you mean you need the insert id?

Comment: or just take out the execution and do it outside the method, and do it explicitly yourself

Comment: `$result->user_id` doesn't make sense for a `prepare` function. That drastically limits the scope of that function.